# Java - crop image using trapezoid shape

Tags: java, image-processing

I need to crop an image using trapezoid shape,
frankly, I have no idea how to start?
I know how to crop using rectangular (well just call the function)....

This is a server side operation. no GUI

10x

Comment: What have you tried?  What tools do you have available?  Are you using AWT?  Swing?  SWT?  JavaFX?  No GUI?

Comment: no GUI. I dont mind using any framewrok u mentioned

Comment: `Graphics#setClip`

Comment: Amazing. you've made my day!!! thanks